# Firebase Database not uploading value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going mad, this code worked a while ago and now it's not...via the debugger all works good but when i refresh my database i see nothing....
**Problem is that it's not uploading to the database.**

Rules are set to

> ".read": "true",
>           ".write": "true"

```
public class MainViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainViewFragment";
    private RecyclerView mView;
    private List<Product> mProducts;
    private DatabaseReference mRef;


    public MainViewFragment() {
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Product pr = new Product("title","price");
        mRef.child("products").child(pr.getStringId()).setValue(pr);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_view, container, false);
        mView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.mainViewRecyclerView);


        mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        mView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        MainViewAdapter adapter = new MainViewAdapter(mProducts,getActivity());
        mView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
}
```

Fragment is called from here

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new MainViewFragment()).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container2,new SecondProductFragment()).commit();
```

**In the debugger, after the code tries to setValue(), it gives me this error**

> No such instance field: 'mRef'

Comment: What is the issue? Can you elaborate the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda the problem is that it's not uploading

Comment: try to change this : `mRef.child("products").child(pr.getStringId()).setValue(pr).push();`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez it's not letting me add it at the end, i added it after that line as mRef.push() , and still nothing.

Comment: If you are using only `mRef.child("products").child("Id1").setValue(pr);` is it working?

Comment: @AlexMamo nope still aint working :(

Comment: Is your MainViewFragment even loaded?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it is, i updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

go for this link:

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/note-it-b6f1c/database/note-it-b6f1c/rules

and set rules here as:

```
 {
   "rules": {
   "foo": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
   }
 }
```

this might solve your problem

Comment: i have the rules set up, sorry for not displaying then earlier , i've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

try to save your data using a map.

So replace this:

```
     public MainViewFragment() {
     mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
     Product pr = new Product("title","price");
     mRef.child("products").child(pr.getStringId()).setValue(pr);

     }
```

with this

```
      public MainViewFragment() {
      mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").push();
      //make a map
       Map map=new HashMap();
       map.put("title","any_title");
       map.put("price","any_price");
       //write the data
       mRef.setValue(map);

       }
```

and make sure that (MainViewFragment()) is being called.